# Iterate in order through a list of objects - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, list

I have a list of objects named Machines. Every machine has a "*Priority*" property (UInteger).
I'm trying to pick Machines from this list (i.e. add them to another list) in a specific order (from lowest to highest priority), till a condition is respected.

Thus I wanted to know if the following method works for that :

```
MachineList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Priority.CompareTo(y.Priority))
For Each machin In MachineList
            MachinesToDisableList.AddMachine(machin)
            If [Condition] Then
                Exit For
            End If
Next
```

The goal is to add Machines to the second list from the lowest to the Highest priority, and stop when it's enough.
But I'm not sure with my solution if I'll iterate in the correct order to get the result expected.

Is that good ? Or the solution is somewhere else ?

Comment: it should be pretty easy to add a Debug.Print to see if they are ordered how you want.  or just use the mouse and hold it over the list in a debug break

Comment: Unless you specifically need `MachineList` sorted, why not use `For Each machin In MachineList.OrderBy(Function(m) m.Priority)`?

Comment: I get an error with `For Each machin In MachineList.OrderBy(Function(m) m.Priority)`.
But the Debug.Print inside the `For Each` gave me something good, thank !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just iterate through the list ordered by the priority. Something like this:

```
    Dim machineList As New List(Of Machine)
    Dim machinesToDisableList As New List(Of Machine)
    machineList.Add(New Machine With {.Priority = 6})
    machineList.Add(New Machine With {.Priority = 2})
    machineList.Add(New Machine With {.Priority = 10})

    For Each machine In machineList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Priority)
        machinesToDisableList.Add(machine)
        If [Condition] Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: That's it. Just I don't know why but the statement `machineList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Priority)` do not works for me.
I need to do in 2 separate lines, and as above, with Function(x,y)... normal ?